# Disable Result Cache (Redis) on Dev Env - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, redis, predis

I want to disable result caching while on the development enviroment.

I do not want to comment caching codes or remove them while on dev env.

Is there any way to disable caching while on dev env?

I'm using SNCRedisBundle & Predis for Symfony2 with Redis.

Sample single result codes:

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$predis = new \Snc\RedisBundle\Doctrine\Cache\RedisCache();
$predis->setRedis(new \Predis\Client());

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('s')
    ->from('CSSliderBundle:Slider', 's')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('s.title', ':title'))
    ->setParameter('title', $title);

$slider = $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->useResultCache(true, 3600 * 1.5) // added this line
    ->setResultCacheDriver($predis)
    ->setResultCacheLifetime(86400)
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

And second question:

Is there any way to clear cache after insert / update with doctrine build-in? I know i can use lifecycleevents but i wonder if any other option available...

Full config:

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://localhost
            logging: %kernel.debug%
            options:
              prefix: "%redis_prefix%"
        cache:
            type: predis
            alias: cache
            dsn: redis://localhost/1
            logging: true
            options:
              prefix: "%redis_prefix%"
        cluster:
            type: predis
            alias: cluster
            dsn:
                - redis://127.0.0.1/2
                - redis://127.0.0.2/3
                - redis://pw@/var/run/redis/redis-1.sock/4
                - redis://127.0.0.1:6379/5
            options:
                profile: 2.4
                connection_timeout: 10
                connection_persistent: true
                read_write_timeout: 30
                iterable_multibulk: false
                throw_errors: true
                cluster: Snc\RedisBundle\Client\Predis\Connection\PredisCluster
        monolog:
            type: predis
            alias: monolog
            dsn: redis://localhost/6
            logging: false
        options:
            connection_persistent: true
    session:
        client: default
        use_as_default: true
    doctrine:
        metadata_cache:
            client: cache
            entity_manager: default
            document_manager: default
        result_cache:
            client: cache
            entity_manager: default
            namespace: "doctrine_result_cache_%kernel.environment%_"
        query_cache:
            client: cache
            entity_manager: default
    monolog:
        client: monolog
        key: monolog
    swiftmailer:
        client: default
        key: swiftmailer
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inject result cache impl to doctrine each time. Just configure your snc_redis bundle like this:

```
snc_redis:
    # other options here..

    doctrine:
        result_cache:
            client: cache # your redis cahce_id connection
            entity_manager: default  # you may specify multiple entity_managers
            namespace: "doctrine_result_cache_%kernel.environment%_"
```

After that, you can disable it for config_dev.yml

Enable caching for $query:

```
    // public function useResultCache($bool, $lifetime = null, $resultCacheId = null)
    $query->useResultCache(true, 3600 * 1.5);
```

More docs: https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#doctrine-caching

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan, use `$query->useResultCache(true, 3600 * 1.5);` for your query.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan enable snc_redis via config, as described in my answer.